# Set Background image to a page/screen in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make an app, using Xamarin Forms, in Visual Studio 2015. I want to add background image to the screen/page. So far, I have reached here, as seen in the below code but it doesn't work.

This is my MainPage.XAML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrackMyMeds"
             x:Class="TrackMyMeds.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="/Images/blue_gradient">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" Padding="8,15,8,0">

        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Welcome to TrackMyMeds" TextColor="White" FontSize="40" FontAttributes="Bold">

        </Label>

        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Let us take charge of your health" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18">

        </Label>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,40,0,15">
            <Label Text="If you already have an account:" TextColor="Black">

            </Label>

            <Button Clicked="LoginPage_Clicked" Text="Log In Here!" BackgroundColor="#387ef5" TextColor="White" FontSize="18">

            </Button>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,0">
            <Label Text="If you're new here then:" TextColor="Black">

            </Label>

            <Button Clicked="SignupPage_Clicked" Text="Sign Up Here!" BackgroundColor="#387ef5" TextColor="White" FontSize="18">

            </Button>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is my MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TrackMyMeds
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }

        private void SignupPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new SignupPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the image file? In the Forms project or in the iOS and Android projects?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the image file name to MainPage.xaml file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BgImgTestApp"
             x:Class="BgImgTestApp.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="mobilebg.png">
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

Add your image file to respective folders.
For Android: Resources --> Drawable folder,
For iOS: Resources folder,
For Windows & Windows Phone: Assets folder.
You need to do these three changes in MainPage.xaml file for setting Background for Windows Desktop App and Windows Phone App.

1.Remove "Form: WindowsPage", switch to "Page".
 2.Add Image Source

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="BgImgTestApp.Windows.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BgImgTestApp.Windows"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image Source="Assets/mobilebg.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

3.comment this:

MainPage.xaml.cs

//LoadApplication(new .....App());

Find the working sample app here: https://github.com/abhiguptame/xamarinsamples/tree/master/BgImgTestApp

Note: You may put resized images according to your device and platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you're viewing on Android you need to keep the file in the the drawable folder of the android project then simply

```
<ContentPage BackgroundImage = "image.jpg">... </ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it Right, Just reduced image size and dragged and dropped to the specific folders in Android-->Resources-->drawable directory and iOS resources directory.

Thanks anyways.