# How to expand image like a background from url on stacklayout using xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to set a image from url like a background but when I use fill and expand this property not work.

```
<Frame
                   BorderColor="Black"
                   CornerRadius="10"
                   HasShadow="True"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent">

            <StackLayout>
              

                 <Image x:Name="backgroundImage"
                           Source="https://www.4freephotos.com/medium/batch/Scattered-clouds276.jpg"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/> 

                <Label Text="Current Data" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   TextTransform="Uppercase"
                   FontSize="20"/>

                <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                      Padding="0,20,0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                 

                    <Label Text="Clouds"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                     <Label Text="W.Speed"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label Text="Humidity"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label Text="Pressure"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label Text="Chance"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label Text="Rain"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label Text="Snow"
                            Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="6"
                            FontSize="9"/>

                    <Image x:Name="IconClouds"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>

                    <Image x:Name="IconWindSpeed"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>

                    <Image x:Name="IconHumidity"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="2"/>

                    <Image x:Name="IconPressure"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="3"/>

                     <Image x:Name="IconChanceOfRain"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="4"/>

                    <Image x:Name="IconRainValue"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="5"/>

                    <Image x:Name="IconSnowValue"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="6"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Clouds.All, StringFormat='{0:0}%'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           FontSize="9"/>

                     <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Wind.Speed, StringFormat='{0:0}m/s'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           FontSize="9"/>

                     <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Main.Humidity, StringFormat='{0:0}%'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           FontSize="9"/>

                     <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Main.Pressure, StringFormat='{0:0}hPa'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="3"
                           FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label x:Name="ChanceOfRainLbl"
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="4"
                           FontSize="9"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].RainForecast.RainForecastValue, StringFormat='{0}mm'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="5"
                           FontSize="9"/>
                    
                    <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue, StringFormat='{0}mm'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="6"
                           FontSize="9"/>

                     
                </Grid>

                <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WeatherForecast[0].DescriptionForecast}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   TextTransform="Uppercase"
                   FontSize="20"/>

            <Image x:Name="IconCurrentTemp"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Title}"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="15"/>

            <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Sys.Country}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="15"/>

            <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Main.Temperature, StringFormat='{0:0}°C'}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="40"/>

            <Label x:Name="HighLowTemperature" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="15"/>

            <Image x:Name="IconFeelsLike"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Label x:Name="FeelsLike" 
                   Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="15"/>

            </StackLayout>
             </Frame>
```

Is there a way to set this image on the Stacklayout ?

I try to put the closed tag  before closed tag  but this not worked.

How can i make the picture as background ?

I have a lot Stacklayouts who need a background.

Comment: StackLayout will arrange items one by one either vertical or horizontal. If you want to have image in the background and on top of it you want to show controls. Then use GridLayout. Or similar layout controls or ContentPage's BackgroundImage property as per the reference link. Pls [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196029/set-background-image-to-a-page-screen-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RelativeLayout` instead of `StackLayout` and add the image first.

```
 <Frame
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        BorderColor="Black"
        CornerRadius="10"
        HasShadow="True">
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Image
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                       Property=Height,
                                                                       Factor=0.5}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                      Property=Width,
                                                                      Factor=1}"
                Source="https://www.4freephotos.com/medium/batch/Scattered-clouds276.jpg" />
            <StackLayout RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}">
                <!--<Image
                    x:Name="backgroundImage"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    Source="https://www.4freephotos.com/medium/batch/Scattered-clouds276.jpg" />-->

                <Label
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                    Text="Current Data"
                    TextTransform="Uppercase" />

                  ........
                  ........
                  ........

                </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </Frame>
```

[image]